# Can my conditional statement be based off of data types?

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement

```
//capture input value for peak size and return 
public static int GetPeakSize()
{
    //declare variables, intitialize and parse after input
    int peak;
    Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter the peak size (must be a number 1-10): ");
    peak = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    //if user enter anything that is not inside the 1-10 range, default
    //to 3
    if (peak < 1 || peak > 10)
    {
        peak = 3;
    }

    return peak;
}
```

In the method above I'm just trying to gather input, parse it, and if the input does not fall in the range of 1-10, return a default value of 3. But instead of just validating numerical input, I want to return a default value of 3 if ANYTHING but the numerical values of 1-10 are entered. So if they enter "four" instead of 4, I'd like the value to default to 3. I wish I could do something along the lines of if (value != int || value < 1 || value > 10)......default = 3. I know this can't be done but is there anyway around it?

Comment: Why not just disallow non-numerical input? If they enter "four" display a message that says "Please enter numbers only." Seems confusing for the user to enter "four" and just have the program silently assume 3.

Comment: @eddie_cat Yeah I know, it's assignment requirements though.

Comment: gotcha, just figured it was worth noting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use `TryParse` instead:

```
    int peak;
    Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter the peak size (must be a number 1-10): ");
    if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out peak) || peak < 1 || peak > 10)
    {
        peak = 3;
    }
```

The code above will attempt to parse the input into an `int` -- if it could not, or if the parsed value falls outside of your range constraints, it overrides `peak` to `3` before continuing on.

**EDIT**: Missed the range constraints.

Comment: Very nice. I'm glad it's that simple. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `int.TryParse`. `int.Parse` will throw if the input is non-numeric.

```
int peak = 0;
bool parseSuccess = int.TryParse(input, out peak);

if (!parseSuccess || peak < 1 || peak > 10)
{

}
```

int.TryParse will return false if the input is not valid, and if it is valid, then the parsed value will be contained in the "out" parameter (`peak` in this case).

Comment: I like this as an alternative to Cory's answer. Will use either one. Thank you.